# Baggage Transfer

Tags: luggage, airport-transfer, del

Is there any Baggage Transfer desk or any private company(ies) to provide baggage transfer services for international travelers at the Indira Gandhi International Airport?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘baggage transfer’? Do you mean, transfer from the plane to your home or office address in India? Or do you mean, transfer between two airlines at the airport?